# Python to do permutation

Tags: python, permutation

I want to define a function that could do the permutation for the input. The input is a group of list like:

```
[[(u'sss',)], [(u'ssss',), (u'sssssss',)], [(u'121',), (u'222',)]] .
```

I want to have this as the input. For the permutation, I need to add the text "title" between each text of the list. So, the output of the function would be looked like:

```
'sss'+'title'+'ssss'+'title'+'121'+'title'
'sss'+'title'+'ssss'+'title'+'222'+'title'
'sss'+'title'+'sssss'+'title'+'121'+'title'    
'sss'+'title'+'sssss'+'title'+'222'+'title'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` and `.join`:

```
from itertools import product

l = [[(u'sss',)], [(u'ssss',), (u'sssssss',)], [(u'121',), (u'222',)]]
result = [''.join(token + 'title' for [token] in tokens) for tokens in product(*l)]
```

Output:

```
['ssstitlesssstitle121title',
 'ssstitlesssstitle222title',
 'ssstitlessssssstitle121title',
 'ssstitlessssssstitle222title']
```

Comment: Given each `tuple` is a one-tuple, you could just unpack them and save a separate loop structure, changing `token for tup in tups for token in tup` to `token for token, in tups` (or `token for [token] in tups` if you're worried the trailing comma is too subtle).

Comment: Thx for the help and suggestion